# Quarkus Hibernate Reactive panache mysql

Tags: java, quarkus, reactive, quarkus-panache, hibernate-reactive

I am trying to build a small app with Reactive jackson hibernate panache mysql as DB.

I am getting the below error.

> "stackTrace": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No pool has been
> defined for persistence unit default-reactive\n\tat
> io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.registerVertxAndPool(FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.java:233)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.rewireMetadataAndExtractServiceRegistry(FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.java:180)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.java:156)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.java:82)\n\tat
> javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)\n\tat
> javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$LazyPersistenceUnit.get(JPAConfig.java:118)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig.startAll(JPAConfig.java:42)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig_Subclass.startAll$$superaccessor5(JPAConfig_Subclass.zig:769)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig_Subclass$$function$$5.apply(JPAConfig_Subclass$$function$$5.zig:29)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:51)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig_Subclass.startAll(JPAConfig_Subclass.zig:727)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.HibernateOrmRecorder.startAllPersistenceUnits(HibernateOrmRecorder.java:88)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.deployment.steps.HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits951856026.deploy_0(HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits951856026.zig:74)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.deployment.steps.HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits951856026.deploy(HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits951856026.zig:40)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:751)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:90)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:100)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:66)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:42)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:119)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:29)\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)\n\tat
> io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$3.run(StartupActionImpl.java:134)\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)\n"

Any idea What am missing?.

I have models

```
@Entity
public class Nation extends PanacheEntity {

    @Column
    public String country;

    public Nation(String country, List<State> states) {
        this.country = country;
        this.states = states;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    public List<State> states = new ArrayList<>();

    public Nation() {

    }
}

@Entity
public class State extends PanacheEntity {

    public State(String state, List<District> districts) {
        this.state = state;
        this.districts = districts;
    }

    @Column
    public String state;

    @OneToMany
    public List<District> districts = new ArrayList<>();

    public State() {

    }
}


@Entity
public class District extends PanacheEntity {

    public District(String district, List<Village> villages) {
        this.district = district;
        this.villages = villages;
    }

    @Column
    public String district;

    @OneToMany
    public List<Village> villages = new ArrayList<>();

    public District() {

    }
}


@Entity
public class Village extends PanacheEntity {

    @Column
    public String village;

    public Village(String village) {
        this.village = village;
    }

    public Village() {

    }
}


@Path("/nation")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApplicationScoped
public class NationResource {

    @Inject
    NationRepository nationRepository;

   /* @Inject
    public NationResource(NationRepository nationRepository) {
        this.nationRepository = nationRepository;
    }*/

    @POST
    @Path("save")
    public Uni<Void> saveNation(Nation nation) {
        return nationRepository.persist(nation);
    }

    @GET
    public Uni<List<Nation>> getNations() {
        return nationRepository.listAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Uni<Nation> getNation(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return nationRepository.findById(id);
    }
}


quarkus:
  http:
    port: 4754
  log:
    console:
      json:
        pretty-print: true
        date-format: "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        exception-output-type: "detailed-and-formatted"
  # configure your datasource
  datasource:
    db-kind: mysql
    username: root
    password: root
    reactive:
      url: vertx-reactive:mysql://localhost:3306/garrsolutions
  # drop and create the database at startup (use `update` to only update the schema)
  hibernate-orm:
    database:
      generation: drop-and-create
```

Comment: What version of quarkus are you using ?

Comment: Which dependencies are you using?

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this problem by adding below snip into pom.xml dependencies:

```xml
<!-- JDBC driver dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: for reactive apps , this is the dependency one would need, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Except that it needs to be `mysql` and not `pg`

Comment: Also, that's not a JDBC driver but a Vert.x client

Answer (score 4):

In my case, i was trying to use H2 Db and i got the same problem. I resolved this problem using a map based approach like the exemple:

From:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2 
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:guitars
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create 
quarkus.hibernate-orm.packages=package br.com.mp.product.models
```

To:

```
quarkus.datasource."guitars".db-kind=h2
quarkus.datasource."guitars".jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:guitars
quarkus.hibernate-orm."guitars".database.generation=drop-and-create 
quarkus.hibernate-orm."guitars".packages=package br.com.mp.product.models
```

In this way the hibernate can find the specified class from map, but i didn't try with MySql Db like is your case.

I saw this example in this link: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm